# labeling trees in haskell

Tags: haskell, tree, monads, state-monad

I have an arbitrary tree and want to transform it into a tree of integers, the original values should be replaced by integers.  The same value has to be replaced by the same number at every occurrence.

function for traversing tree is provided, and this is my labeling function

```
label :: Ord a => a -> State (Store a Int) Int
```

I believe i need a stack to store labels, but i'm not sure how to apply it
, any guidance would be appreciated

Comment: A stack would not be appropriate here, but it looks like `Store` is a type of map that is handling the mapping of a piece of data to an integer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a traversal function

```
traverse :: (Traversable t, Applicative f) => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f (t b)
```

as given by the `Traversable` typeclass, then you have `f ~ State (Store a Int)`, so

```
traverse label :: (Ord a, Traversable t) => t a -> State (Store a Int) (t Int)
```

so you should just be able to apply `traverse label` to your tree, then execute that state action to get your labeled tree, so in full it would be

```
labelTree :: (Tree t, Ord a) => t a -> Store a Int -> (t Int, Store a Int)
labelTree tree labelStore = runState (traverse label tree) labelStore
```

I've provided `labelStore` as an argument because it may be desirable to provide this function with a set of existing labels, and because it isn't clear how to construct a new `Store`.

However, I'll point out that there's nothing special about even using a tree here, any `Traversable` would be sufficient, so you could apply this to lists, `Map`s, custom types, or whatever, provided it's a `Traversable` container holding `Ord a => a` values.